# How can I detect new opened window with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have a page where facebook like button pops up a new window to confirm the like. How can I detect when the window opens/closes?

The reason I'm asking this is because facebook provides a way to subscribe to an event when the like is confirmed, but there doesn't seem to be any way to detect that the user canceled the confirmation(either by closing the window or clicking "Cancel" instead of "Confirm").

Any ideas appreciated :)